# Angular 2 - bypasscecurity

Tags: security, angular, sanitize

I habe problem with the "security" of angular 2. I try to calculate a span-witdh within a ngfor-loop:

```html
<span style="width:updateStyle({{ ((date | amDifference : item.startdate : 'minutes' :true)/item.duration*100) | round }})%  .....more span>
```

And import/changed a bypass-security.component from internet:

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeStyle, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'bypass-security',
    templateUrl: 'app/bypass-security.component.html',
})

export class BypassSecurityComponent {
    dangerousUrl: string;
    trustedUrl: SafeUrl;

    dangerrousStyle: string;
    trustedStyle: SafeStyle;

    // #docregion trust-url
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        // javascript: URLs are dangerous if attacker controlled.
        // Angular sanitizes them in data binding, but you can
        // explicitly tell Angular to trust this value:
        this.dangerousUrl = 'javascript:alert("Hi there")';
        this.trustedUrl = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.dangerousUrl);
        this.trustedStyle = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(this.dangerrousStyle);
    }

    updateStyle(id: string)
    {
        this.trustedStyle = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(this.id);
    }
}
```

But still get this error:
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value width:83%; height:3px; background-color:#d9d9d4; display:inline-block; (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Calling methods from view bindings is usually bad practice because this method is called every time Angular2 checks for changes (runs change detection)

I don't really get what you try to accomplish, but if you want to set the width in `%` do something like

```
<span [style.width.%]="width">
```

and assign the value you want to be used for `width` to a property with that name

```
constructor() { 
  this.width = updateStyle(((date | amDifference : item.startdate : 'minutes' :true)/item.duration*100) | round }}) 
  // I have a really hard time figuring out what this is supposed to do
```

I used the constructor only for an example. do the calculation whenever you think it should be updated (some event, some lifecycle callback, ...)